# How to get Password Restrictions from Okta API?

Tags: .net, okta

I'm using Okta as base for a custom user management web solution. In the back end I have ASP.NET I'm using OKTAs specific SDK to communicate with okta from there.

In the front end I'm using an Angular based UI but not communicating to Okta from here (no CORS). I'm able to sign in, validate session, CRUD operations in groups and users, so almost everything is working just fine except password restrictions.

I don't want to hardcode but to get them dynamically through an API and show password complexity limitations in a tool tip or validate my form. I can find the model object to use but I don't know how to get it through an API, don't know which client object would include this policy, password policy, or complexity object as a GET method. Documentations is poor, so if anyone can help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to retrieve the password complexity rules from the Okta API, but it's not well-documented yet. The [Policy API](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/policy.html) is what you're looking for.

This API isn't supported in the Okta .NET SDK, but you can make a raw HTTP request to list all the password policies:

```
GET https://dev-xxxxx.oktapreview.com/api/v1/policies?type=PASSWORD
Authorization: SSWS your-token

200 OK
[
  {
    "type": "PASSWORD",
    "id": "00p9o1nik8khgmupS0h7",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "name": "Default Policy",
    // snip...
    "settings": {
      "password": {
        "complexity": {
          "minLength": 8,
          "minLowerCase": 1,
          "minUpperCase": 1,
          "minNumber": 1,
          "minSymbol": 0,
          "excludeUsername": true
        },
      },
      // snip...
    },
    // snip...
  }
]
```

You should be able to pull out the complexity rules and render them for the user.

Full disclosure: I work at Okta. (And I'll make sure there's an easier way to do this in the future!)

Comment: Thank you, very much! I was struggling on finding the path to do it through different clients with .NET SDK and couldn't. Now I can confirm what are my options in the future. Thank you too you for taking care on this inside OKTA, appreciate it!